# Change @RequestBody object based on @PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Below is my application code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "app/{version}/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public RegisterMemberResponse registerMember(@Valid @RequestBody RegisterMemberRequest request,@PathVariable Integer version){
    return registerservice.register(request);
}
```

for app version 1 my  RegisterMemberRequest class is

```
public class RegisterMemberRequest{
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    //gatter & setter...
}
```

and for app version 2 my request class is

```
public class LatestRegisterMemberRequest extends RegisterMemberRequest{
    @NotNull
    private String middleName;
    //getter & setter...
}
```

so how i can i change my registerMember() method in such a way that i can serve both version 1 & 2 request uri.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hardcode the version number into the url (which I would not recommend), you could easily use two different controller methods with hardcoded paths like `app/v1/register` and `app/v2/register`.

Another way would be to use content negotiation and route the requests according to a given content-type, e.g. `application/vnd+<YOURCOMPANY>.<DATATYPE_AND_VERSION>+json`, also using separate rest controller methods annotated with `@Consumes`.

Comment: So according to your first paragraph if i have 10 version of application i have to write 10 method and all of it contains 80-90 % same code.

i did not get want to say in second paragraph.

Comment: Of course you introduce some more methods, but you also expose more rest interfaces. If you have common logic, you can easily extract the common stuff into an own method or probably even call `registerV1()` from `registerV2()`. If you expose some rest interfaces for the public, you should better not end up in supporting ten different versions of the same interface, cause it will be really hard to use your api then.

Comment: The second paragraph is about another option to provide different methods but based on the content-type header instead of a url. So your url is always `app/register` but called with different header values `application/vnd+ABC.register-v1+json` and `application/vnd+ABC.register-v2+json`. But all in all the preferred way is to build more robust and backwards compatible apis and therefore not using all auto-magic validation stuff. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle

Comment: Thanks @ajaegle for your interest to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of [Requestmapping-uri-templates-regex](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) , version number will be the `@PathVariable` write your business logic to decide what should be the response body depends on pathvariable version.

Comment: Hi Lovababu,
I think you didnot get actual question its not about request mapping with path variable its about change the request object according to path variable value.